# Set up a TV like RTMP channel

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtmp, wowza

I'm looking for the best way to play a sequence of videos at specific times on a RTMP channel. Right now, I've setup a few things that seem viable to achieve this :

1. Setup a Wowza Streaming Engine on a server
2. Setup a Wowza Streaming Cloud account, that receives the stream from the server and broadcasts it with different qualities.

Now I plugged a RTMP stream into the Wowza Cloud and was able to play it in different qualities on all browsers and devices. That's the end game.

I was able to play videos on the stream using ffmpeg and started to work on having video playlists running.

So my question is simple :

Do you think it's a good way to do this ? How would you do it otherwise ?

Thanks
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One pitfall when using `ffmpeg` is that launching distinct, sequencial commands to feed your RTMP stream can cause client disconnects because you have timing discontinuities when switching to a new video.

You can use the [ffmpeg concatenation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) options to stream a list of files without timing issues.

There is also a way of managing playlists directly in Wowza using a custom server module. There's a [StreamManager](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?145-How-to-schedule-streaming-with-Wowza-Streaming-Engine-%28ServerListenerStreamPublisher%29) module in the Wowza add-on collection which you can use to schedule videos. The source code is provided so you can tailor it how you see fit.

Comment: For those who want more info on setting up the StreamManager, you can check my post here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29104416/how-to-schedule-streaming-with-wowza-streaming-engine/29119341#29119341